# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Tags: symfony

i am doing a jobeet projet with symfony 2.8 when a write this command composer require --dev doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle i got this error

> Problem 1 - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.2.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.1 3, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3. 4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2. 4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2]. - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.2.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.1 3, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3. 4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2. 4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2]. - doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.2.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^3.4|^4.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.1 3, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3. 4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2. 4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.2]. - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.13|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.14|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.15|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.16|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.17|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.18|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.19|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.20|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.21|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.22|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.23|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.24|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.25|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.26|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.27|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.28|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.29|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v3.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.11|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.12|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v4.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.51 - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v2.8.51, required as 2.8.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.51]. - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle ^3.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle[3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2].

Installation failed, reverting `./composer.json` to its original content. how can i fixe it please?

this is my composer json configuration

```
{ "name": "logic/symfony2.8", "license": "proprietary", "type": "project",

 "autoload": { "psr-4": { "": "src/" }, "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", 

"app/AppCache.php" ] }, "require": { "php": ">=5.3.9", "symfony/symfony":

 "2.8.*", "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8", "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4", 

"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3", "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4", 

"sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0", "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",

 "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0" }, "require-dev": { 

"sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0", "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7" }, "scripts":

 { "post-install-cmd": [ 

"Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget" ],

 "post-update-cmd": [ 

"Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",

 "Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile", 

"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget" ] },

 "config": { "bin-dir": "bin" }, "extra": { 

"symfony-app-dir": "app", "symfony-web-dir": "web", "symfony-assets-install": "relative", "incenteev-parameters": { "file": "app/config/parameters.yml" } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

**composer require** always download the latest version which is not compatible with Symfony 2.8.

you need to specify the right version for symfony 2.8

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle:version
```